# How to Get Print Job Like As a file Using Java

Tags: java, file-handling

I am trying to get print job like as file format means i want capture and save the file using java.Can anybody help.I am trying in dos commands also in java but unable to get print job and save the file format.

```
try{ 
            PrintService DefaultprinterName = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            PrintService[] printerList = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            PrinterJob setDefaultprinter = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();            
            System.out.println(DefaultprinterName.getName());            
            int no = 1;
            for (PrintService printer : printerList){
                System.out.println("Printer number " + no + ": " + printer.getName()); 
                no++;
            }            
            Scanner inChoosePrinter = new Scanner(System.in);            
            System.out.print("Choose a Printer as default: ");
            String s = inChoosePrinter.nextLine();            
            if (Integer.parseInt(s) > printerList.length){
                System.out.println("Selection not in range. Try again");
                System.exit(0);
            }            
            int selectedPrinter = (Integer.parseInt(s)-1);
            setDefaultprinter.setPrintService(printerList[selectedPrinter]);             
            System.out.println("You have selected " + printerList[selectedPrinter]);
            String sp = printerList[selectedPrinter].toString();
            sp = sp.substring(16);
            Process p2;            
            if (!sp.startsWith("\\")){
                p2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c wmic printer where name='"+sp+"' call setdefaultprinter");
            }else{
                p2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n " + sp);
            }            
            Scanner inGetFile = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Type full path of a file to print: ");
            String filename = inGetFile.nextLine();
            //Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /min notepad /p c:\\users\\hesperus13\\printsample.txt");
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /min notepad /p " + filename);
            p.waitFor(); 
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
            String line=reader.readLine(); 
            while(line!=null) 
            { 
                System.out.println(line); 
                line=reader.readLine(); 
            }
            Process p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c wmic printjob get");
            p1.waitFor();
            String str1 = null;
            BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream())); 
            str1 = reader1.readLine();
            if (str1!=null){
                System.out.println("The print job is in queue");
                System.out.println("Done printing"); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no file to print"); 
            }
            //Process p5=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c wmic printer where name='"+DefaultprinterName+"' call setdefaultprinter");
            //Process p5=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n " + DefaultprinterName);
            if (!sp.startsWith("\\")){
                p2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c wmic printer where name='"+DefaultprinterName.getName()+"' call setdefaultprinter");
            }else{
                p2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n " + DefaultprinterName.getName());
            }
```

Comment: Can you copy the code.

Comment: Edit Your post.. (style Your code)

Comment: What is your expected result and what is the actual result?

Comment: I want get file as same format and saved into one folder using java, when i given the print.It is possible?

Comment: wmic command for printjob is quite simple. Because it will show all the currently printing activities.